# Are there any other known members of Anbu: Root, apart from Sai and Danzou?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, apart from Sai and Danzou, which other characters were members of the secret subdivision of Anbu, Root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At one point, [Yamato](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yamato) was a member of Root. This is true in both anime and manga. Kakashi was also a member of [Root](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake), but this is only true in the anime. [Yamanaka Fuu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/F%C5%AB_Yamanaka) and [Aburame Tatsuma](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tatsuma_Aburame), the two ninja Danzo brought to the Five Kage summit was also member of Root. For a full list of Root members, see the [wikia page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Root).

Credits to Ero Sennin for pointing me the Root wikia page.